# How to trigger the Spring Boot CRON job automatically when tomcat is up and running?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, cron

I have created CRON job using spring boot process and this job will repeat the execution for every 1 hour. From eclipse, it is working fine. Now, Spring Boot application (CRON Job) has exported as war file and put it in tomcat with default port 8080.

Tomcat has started successfully and running, but CRON job is not started.
**Application.java**

```
package com.task;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})ppublic class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Jar Execution File**

```
@Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        String gitPath = null;
        String rallyPath = null;
        String chefPath = null;
        String jenkinsPath = null;
        try {

            // Data Pull from jenkins
            jenkinsPath = PropertyManager.getProperty("Jenkins_FILE_PATH", "application.properties");
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar " + jenkinsPath  + " cmd");


        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } 


        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
```

I have added the below dependency in **pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.task</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-batchtask</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringBatch</name>
    <description>Spring Batch-Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.task.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

How to trigger the Spring Boot CRON job automatically when tomcat is up and running?

Comment: Those should trigger automatically. If they don't you have either created a wrong WAR of are using the scheduling in a wrong way.

Comment: Already, I have created many different war files  and those are working fine. But those applications have a UI page. But this CRON job doesn't have UI and just execute the jar file to pull the data from jenkins tool. What is the error in this war?

Comment: If it is a war it is a war. UI or no UI doesn't matter. What is wrong with it you are expecting us to guess that from the 5 lines of a single dependency in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I have updated with my file details and please let me know, is this file have an any issue?

Comment: Your class isn't extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

Comment: Yes, Already i have extended the file like this `public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer`. But it is throwing error of `The hierarchy of the type Application is inconsistent`.

Comment: Not according to what you posted here. I you don't extend that class your application will not start.

Comment: I have updated my post and also tried with extending, but showing error.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/johnjvester/jpa-spec-with-quartz watch out.